# JQuery Selector Find

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li>
        <a id="my_name_is_1" href="#">...</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="my_name_is_2" href="#">...</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="my_name_is_3" href="#">...</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="my_name_is_4" href="#">...</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How to select the anchor tag with id 'my_name_is3'. Something like:

```
var thenumber = "3";
$("ul.mylist").find("li>a#my_name_is_"+thenumber).append("okay");
```

Comment: The code you provided, while not the most efficient, will work if you identify classes by class and ids by id. Change `<ul id="mylist">` to `<ul class="mylist">` or `ul.mylist` to `ul#mylist`. http://jsfiddle.net/uF24D/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/RuhnL/)***

Concatenate a string using thenumber. Keep in mind that finding elements by id is best because the ids are unique.

```
var thenumber = "3";
$("#my_name_is_"+thenumber).append("okay");
```

Answer (score 3):

`id` attributes are supposed to be unique, so you don't have to specify anything else :

```
var num = 3;
$( "#my_name_is_" + num ).append( "okay" );
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to traverse manually with ID's:

```
$('#my_name_is' + thenumber).append('okay');
```